# Storing user_likes with the Omniauth-Facebook gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

Does anyone know where in the **Auth Hash** the user_likes are stored?

I've tried different combos:

```
auth.extra.raw_info.user_likes
auth.extra.raw_info.likes
```

I've got the permission, I just don't know how to get to the user_likes array.

[Omniauth-Facebook gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook)

**After some time (edit)**

Alternatively I could do something like this using the HTTParty gem:

```
  url = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{auth.uid}/likes&access_token=#{auth.credentials.token}"
  @likes = HTTParty.get(url)
```

But I really want to know if its possible through the omniauth authentication process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The omniauth-facebook gem uses the /me call to fill the raw_info hash. Per the facebook docs http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/, likes are not included in the user object but are a connection that can be accessed by calling https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this response though late, helps someone who is trying to figure out what is inside the different hashes part of auth hash object (schema reference: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema)

Instead of trying different combinations (as posted in the question), one could simply render the object as an yaml to browser. Now page source of the browser output would give a clear picture of what is returned part of the auth object. Other option is to put a debug break and inspect the auth object in the callback controller (an ide would be very helpful in this case).

routes.rb

```
 ...
 match '/auth/facebook/callback' => 'authentications#create'
 ...
```

authentications_controller.rb (or your controller that receives the call back)

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
    ...


    def create
        # a simple code to understand the content of the auth object
        render :text => request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml
    end
 end
```